# Parsing arithmetic expression for long numbers that need formatting

Tags: cocoa-touch, expression, number-formatting

I am trying to make a simple calculator app. Currently, the app works perfectly. One problem: It's smart enough to change results into formatted numbers (800000 = 800,000), but not full expressions (200*600/21000 = 200*600/21,000).

I would like to be able to have a method that I could feed a string and get back a string of properly formatted numbers with operations still inside the string.

Example:

I feed the method 30000/80^2. Method gives back 30,000/80^2.

EDIT: People seem to be misunderstanding the question (Or it's possible I am misunderstanding the answers!) I want to be able to separate the numbers - 60000/200000 would separate into 60000 & 200000. I can do it from there.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Shall the method just take a string and return another string? If so, should it do the parsing itself?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Not exactly. I basically just want a method capable of splitting the expression into numbers and operations, as the edited question states.

Comment: I am sorry you didn't like my edit; I was trying to clarify your question so that potential answerers would understand it better. (N.B.: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) I do respect your authorship, but I'm still going to request that you or I [remove the thanks and signature line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) again, and suggest that you add some formatting and clarify some of your verbiage to make reading easier. Good luck. (And thanks for keeping the corrected tags.)

Comment: You have to define what is a number: Integers? Floating point? In which locale? With separators, or sign characters? Scientific notation? You definitely should use the same parser as for the calculation.

Comment: @joshCaswell I'll remove the sig line. -Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what's the problem? You obviously can parse the whole expression (you say calculator works), you can format single numbers (you say you can format results).

The only thing you need is to parse the expression, format all the numbers and recompose the expression...

**EDIT**: There is a simpler solution. For formatting, you don't need to parse the expression into a tree. You just have to find the numbers.

I suggest to create character set of all operators

```
NSCharacterSet* operators = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+*-/^()"];
NSCharacterSet* whitespaces = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
```

Then split the expression using this set:

```
NSString* expression = [...];
NSMutableString* formattedExpression = [NSMutableString string];
NSRange numberRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
   unichar character = [expression characterAtIndex:i];

   if ([whitespaces characterIsMember:character] || [operators characterIsMember:character]) {
        if (numberRange.length > 0) {
            NSString* number = [expression substringWithRange:numberRange];
            NSString* formattedNumber = [self formatNumber:number];
            [formattedExpression appendString:number];

            numberRange.length = 0;
        }
   }
   else if (numberRange.length == 0) {
       numberRange.location = i;
       numberRange.length = 1;
   }
   else {
       numberRange.length++;
   }

   if ([operators characterIsMember:character]) {
       [formattedExpression appendFormat:@"%C", character];
   }
}

if (numberRange.length > 0) {
    NSString* number = [expression substringWithRange:numberRange];
    NSString* formattedNumber = [self formatNumber:number];
    [formattedExpression appendString:number];
}
```

Note that this should work even for numbers prefixed by a sign. I am ignoring all whitespaces because if you want to have a pretty expression, you probably want to handle whitespaces differently (e.g. no space after (, space before +/-, space after - only if it's not a number sign...). In general, for handling spaces, parsing the expression into a tree would simplify matters. Also note that infix expressions are not unambiguous - that means that you should sometimes add parenthesis. However, that can't be done without parsing into a tree.

Comment: Actually, I use GCMathParser for the parsing, so the parsing is opaque to me. I guess I just want a way to separate the numbers - see edit to original question.

Comment: @ErwaySoftware: You will probably have to find an alternative parser, one that allows you to "tap in", then. [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) is one option (I've never used it). Dave DeLong, who wrote it, is [fairly active](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) here on SO.

Comment: @ErwaySoftware: Thanks, but it's more a tip than an answer. Allow me to suggest that you write up your own, with some detail for future readers (which part of DDMathParser allowed you to do what you need, i.e.) when you have a few minutes.

Comment: Added simple expression formatting code but I suggest to use a parser which lets you work with the expression tree. Things will get much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html).  Not only will that handle formatting of numbers, it will do so based on the user's locale.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do for the result. Actually, I use GCMathParser for the parsing, so the parsing is opaque to me. I guess I just want a way to separate the numbers - see edit to original question.